# google app script trigger for ctrl+x ( cutted ) data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to make a google app script that keeps data synchronized from a google sheet to a local service,

I did an installable `onEdit()` trigger that seems to be working, so, if a end user makes an edition I got the range and update my local copy and that's seems to be working.

The issue is if the end user cuts and paste some data from the spreadsheet, The triggered `onEdit` only show the pasted range so I have no data about the cutted range.
As an example:

The user selects `A1:A1` and cuts the data and paste in `A2:A2` then the `onEdit` trigger only shows the `A2:A2` range, is it possible to get the cutted range or the only solution is to use a timer trigger to keep the data in sync?

Comment: Do a `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` on the event block and use `e.range.rowStart,columnStart,rowEnd` and `columnEnd` to get the entire range.

Comment: Cutting from A1 is one onEdit() and pasting into A2 is another onEdit()

Comment: Hey @Cooper are you getting a trigger every time a user press ctrl+x ?? I'm not getting any onEdit trigger (and that makes sense to me as it's not an edition)

Comment: If a user action changes the value of a cell then I think that generates an onEdit trigger.

Comment: That was my guess too but I'm not getting the trigger, it works if you delete the field / range by pressing delete key but doesn't work if you pres ctr+x and ctrl+v in other place

Comment: Share your code and I'll try debug it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Cooper mentioned in the comments:

> Cutting from A1 is one onEdit() and pasting into A2 is another onEdit()